# Bad Request when running the NPM command

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

Every time after running the npm command like so:

`D:\SPRING\TwentyEight>npm install -g @angular/cli`

I am getting the error below:

```
npm ERR! code E400  
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91912\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-31T19_30_05_856Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you post  please what the log says from here please: `C:\Users\91912\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-31T19_30_05_856Z-debug.log`

Comment: HI@RazRonen  i am getting the following log

Comment: 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'npm@latest',
1 verbose cli   '-g'
1 verbose cli ]

Comment: 2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v14.4.0
4 verbose npm-session de6539afd0103642
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 110ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for npm@latest 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 137ms

Comment: 11 verbose stack Error: 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
12 verbose statusCode 400
13 verbose pkgid npm@latest
14 verbose cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "npm@latest" "-g"

Comment: 17 verbose node v14.4.0
18 verbose npm  v6.14.5
19 error code E400
20 error 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: the main cause of this issue is proxy so after disabling the proxy issue resolved.